# Pulumi / AzureKeyVault import / SkuName mismatch

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, pulumi

I am trying to import existing Azure KeyVault resource into Pulumi (C#, pulumi 2.11.2). I am heaving a problem with specifying right SkuName ("Standard" according to Azure Resource Explorer).
If I set it to:

- "Standard", I am getting:
  `error: azure:keyvault/keyVault:KeyVault resource 'sandbox-pulumi-keyvault' has a problem: expected sku_name to be one of [standard premium], got Standard`
- "standard":  `=   └─ azure:keyvault:KeyVault  sandbox-pulumi-keyvault    import     [diff: ~skuName]; 1 warning` and then of course: `warning: inputs to import do not match the existing resource; importing this resource will fail`

So I am kind of stuck here, running out of the options... Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mateusz

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the relevant code and the errors you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the same error using the latest Azure provider (I have 3.23) but I got no difference while importing. `standard` worked fine in my case.

Anyway, you may want to override the diff that you see during a preview. You can set the `ignoreChanges` option:

```ts
const vault = new azure.keyvault.KeyVault("vault", {
    skuName: "standard",
    // ... other properties
}, {
    import: "/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/myvault",
    ignoreChanges: ["skuName"]
});
```